# How to display multiple row in flask?

Tags: flask

Here's my query..

```
@app.route('/teacher/<username>/files')
def view_files(username):
name = username
 sql = "SELECT fid from files WHERE f_username ='" + name+ "'"        
cur=mysql.connection.cursor()
cur.execute(sql)
for ids in cur.fetchall():
    sql1 = "select f_name from files where fid = %s"  
    cur.execute(sql1,ids)
    vf=cur.fetchall()
    return render_template('view_files.html',vf=vf)

return 'No files uploaded'
```

I'm able to print only first row of the result query. Is the usage of for Loop is proper?

Answer (score 0):

return exits the function, passing the return value to the function's caller.  The first time you call return during your loop, view_files() is exited.

In your for loop, store your returned sql rows into an array.  Pass the array to your view_files.html template.  Use a for loop inside that template to display the results.